# How to get text behind canvas using selenium python

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I want to get text of an email behind canvas, but not finding a way to do it.

I am trying the following code

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://thatsthem.com/phone/806-241-6888')
table=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.row.clearfix.mt15').get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

When I print table I don't see variable behind canvas (like var p1 = "makaya0";). They can be seen in source code when I open "View Page source" on browser. How we can access that variables and get text from them?

Below is page Source

```
<ul class="list-unstyled list-inline record-list">

    <li>
        <span class="label label-info"> <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Mobile</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <i class="fa fa-phone" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Phone Number"></i>
        <h3>
                                                                                                    <span itemprop="telephone">806-241-6889</span>
                                                                                            </h3>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span class="label label-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Valid Email Address</span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <i class="fa fa-envelope" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Email Address"></i>
        <canvas id="c59baf787024e2" width="160" height="20" class="email"></canvas>
        <script id="t2i">
            var p1 = "makaya0";
            var p2 = "923@yah";
            var p3 = "oo.com";
            var c59baf787024e2 = document.getElementById("c59baf787024e2");
            var c59baf787024e2_context = c59baf787024e2.getContext("2d");
            c59baf787024e2_context.fillStyle = "#353535";
            c59baf787024e2_context.font = "98% sans-serif";
            c59baf787024e2_context.textBaseline = "bottom";
            c59baf787024e2_context.fillText(p1 + p2 + p3, 0, 20);
            document.getElementById("t2i").parentElement.removeChild(document.getElementById("t2i"));
        </script>
    </li>

    <li itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <i class="fa fa-home" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Address"></i>
        <a class="no-linky" href="https://thatsthem.com/address/8114-Sherman-Ave-Lubbock-TX-79423">

            <span itemprop="streetAddress">8114 Sherman Ave</span>
            <br/> <i class="fa-placeholder"></i>

            <span itemprop="addressLocality">Lubbock</span>

            <span itemprop="addressRegion">TX</span>

            <span itemprop="postalCode">79423</span>
        </a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: that's because this part is a script (enclosed in a <script> tag) To do this you need to go into javascript mode and get the value of the variable

Comment: Thank you. how can I get all var p1 if there more than one?driver.execute_script("return p1;") return last var p1.

Comment: well i guess what you want id retutn p1+p2+p3

Comment: how to get the "answer" from JS :  
canvas.font = '60px Arial';
canvas.strokeText('Answer: 61655',90,112);  In here i need to return 'Answer' i.e 61655.HOw to Do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the values you are talking about are javascript variables.
they're not 'text' per say.

to run a script in javascript through selenium, you can do:

```
output = self.driver.execute_script("return p1;")
```

and it will put the value of variable `p1` in javascript into the `output` variable in python.

This assumes the variable p1 is in the global context, which it seems to be in your case.

Comment: PS: scrapping email addresses from web site is often against privacy policy, so I would not do this if I were you.